# Where does IIS save a file when it is uploaded?

Tags: iis, file, upload

I wonder where IIS saves the uploaded file? There must be some default directory. Is it possible to save an uploaded file to a user defined directory on IIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a temp folder indeed, but what you usually do is save your uploaded file in the code behind (assuming you are talking about ASP.NET):

aspx-file:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

cs-file:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\\YOUR LOCATION\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

If you need to set the temp folder location for any other reason (which is possible), please elaborate.

Comment: In case of MVC, would it be the same?\

Comment: Basically, yes. The aspx would be the view and the cs the controller.